# Install nuget package without content folder

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec

I need to install a nuget package in my csproj and I would like to prevent the installation of all files contained in the "content" folder of the nuget package.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Nope. It is the nuget convention to add content files to csproj.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do this. If you use [project.json way of managing nuget dependencies](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json), we do not modify your project, irrespective of the content in the content folder.